# Compare the current row with a previous on in R

Tags: r

I want to  delete the entire row if the current value of C is bigger than the previous value, then delete that row

```
A  B   C 
1: 1 10 100
2: 2 20 200 
3: 3 30 800
4: 4 40 400
5: 5 50 500
```

For example, in Row 3: 800 > 200, so delete Row 3

Result:

```
 A  B    C
1: 1 10 100
2: 2 20 200
4: 4 40 400
5: 5 50 500
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Hello, there is not enough detail for others to help. With the rule you specified it should remove all rows except first one. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Comment: why is row 5 not deleted as well? 500 > 400 ?!  and row 2(200) is bigger than 1(100).....

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
your_data[c(diff(your_data$C) >= 0, TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, C <= lead(C, default = C[n()]))
```

**Output:**

```
  A  B   C
1 1 10 100
2 2 20 200
3 4 40 400
4 5 50 500
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1:5, B = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L), C = c(100L, 
200L, 800L, 400L, 500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:"))
```